# How to translate "No husbands are wives" with binary predicates $H(x,y)$ , $W(x,y)$?

Tags: logic

How would you translate the sentence, "No husbands are wives," with these two binary predicates:

$\quad H(x,y)$ is defined to mean "$x$ is the husband of $y$."

$\quad W(x,y)$ is defined to mean "$x$ is the wife of $y$."

There is no predicate $H(x)$ that would mean just "$x$ is a husband."

Therefore, $\exists y\,H(x,y)$ would be the best translation for "$x$ is a husband."

My professor translates the sentence as $\forall x\,\forall y\,(H(x,y)\rightarrow¬W(x,y))$.

That looks to me like it means "No one is husband and wife to the same person," rather than the intended meaning, "If $x$ is the husband of some person, then $x$ is not the wife of any person."

I translated it as $\forall x\, ((\exists y\,H(x,y))\rightarrow(\forall y\, ¬W(x,y)))$.

Is there some way I am misunderstanding the statement $\forall x\,\forall y\,(H(x,y)\rightarrow¬W(x,y))$?

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with you. Yes, your professor's sentence means exactly what you say: No husband is the wife of the person he is the husband of.  And that is not the same as saying that no husbands are wives (of *anyone*). And your translation for that is exactly correct!

For symmetry sake, you could do:

$\forall x (\exists y \: H(x,y) \rightarrow \neg \exists y \: W(x,y))$

which  is of course by a single quantifier negation equivalent to your sentence.